# Analyze the run time of a nested for loops algorithm

Tags: algorithm, loops, time-complexity

Say i have the following code

```
def func(A,n):
  for i = 0 to n-1:
    for k = i+1 to n-1:
      for l = k+1 to n-1:
        if A[i]+A[k]+A[l] = 0:
          return True
```

A is an array, and n denotes the length of A.

As I read it, the code checks if any 3 consecutive integers in A sum up to 0. I see the time complexity as

T(n) = (n-2)(n-1)(n-2)+O(1) => O(n^3)

Is this correct, or am I missing something? I have a hard time finding reading material about this (and I own CLRS)

Comment: This is neither Java nor Python. Don't put irrelevant tags on your questions.

Comment: In short yes. You are correct. The complexity is O(n^3)

Comment: @opensam You are both not correct: it does not require `i`, `k`, `l` to be consecutive.

Comment: This is pseudocode, and i would accept any coding answers in form of python and java, thus i put those tags on there. My bad.
Care to explain what the correct interpretation is? :)@TemporalWolf?

Comment: @hanko see Prune's answer. He explains it well.

Comment: @TemporalWolf but how does i,k,l not being required to be consecutive change the time complexity from O(n^3) to something else? EDIT : I didn't see the part about hanko reading them as have-to-be-consecutive, I only saw the complexity part. My bad

Comment: @opensam it doesn't. I was responding to your original comment, which didn't mention the complexity. His total assessment was not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the functionality wrong: it checks to see whether any three elements add up to 0.  To improve execution time, it considers them only in index order: i < k < j.

You are correct about the complexity.  Although each loop takes a short-cut, that short-cut is merely a scalar divisor on the number of iterations.  Each loop is still **O**(n).

As for the coding, you already have most of it done -- and Stack Overflow is not a coding service.  Give it your best shot; if that doesn't work and you're stuck, post another question.

---

If you really want to teach yourself a new technique, look up Python's [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) package.  You can use this to generate all the combinations in triples.  You can then merely check sum(triple) in each case.  In fact, you can use the [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) method to check whether any one triple sums to 0, which could reduce your function body to a single line of Python code.

I'll leave that research to you.  You'll learn other neat stuff on the way.

---

**Addition for OP's comment.**

Let's set N to 4, and look at what happens:

```
i = 0
for k = 1 to 3
    ... three k loop
i = 1
for k = 2 to 3
    ... two k loops
i = 2
for k = 3 to 3
    ... one k loop
```

The number of k-loop executions is the "triangle" number of n-1: 3 + 2 + 1.  Let m = n-1; the formula is T(m) = m(m-1)/2.

Now, you propagate the same logic to the **l** loops.  You run T(k) loops on **l** for k= 1, 2, 3.  If I recall, this third-order "pyramid" formula is P(m) = m(m-1)(m-2)/6.

In terms of n, this is (n-1)(n-2)(n-3)/6 loops on **l**.  When you multiply this out, you get a straightforward cubic formula in **n**.

Here is the sequence for n=5:

```
0 1 2
0 1 3
0 1 4
    change k
0 2 3
0 2 4
    change k
0 3 4
    change k
    change k
  change l
1 2 3
1 2 4
    change k
1 3 4
    change k
    change k
  change l
2 3 4
```

BTW, **l** is a bad variable name, easily confused with **1**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Could you elaborate a bit on the complexity. How can it still be O(n) for instance if the first loop runs from 0 to n, would the second loop run from n+1 to n? as far as the coding, i dont expect the code, it was just if anyone felt like it was easier to explain using code :-)

Comment: @hanko **each** loop is `O(n)`. The total is `O(n**3)`

Comment: "Each loop is still O(n)." - no, big-O notation does not work that way.